# uiimage animation effect

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uianimation

I'm trying to get a UIImage to have a slight bobbing effect.

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
            [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(endSwipeAnimation)];
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
            [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
            [myImage setAlpha:1.0];
            [myImage setAlpha:0.7];

            [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];

          [UIView commitAnimations];
```

any ideas how to accomplish this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a short video clip of what this is doing at the moment, and a better description of what you want it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:animationID context:context];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
```

are missing... ?

Answer (score 1):

In between animation write what new effect or change u want.

first set imageView alpha value to 1
and then change its alpha value to 0.5 or whatever u want in animation.

Comment: [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(endSwipeAnimation)];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:10];
[myImage setAlpha:0.7];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];